# Symfony - create a second User Class

Tags: php, symfony, inheritance

I have `App\Entity\User` Class.

I want to create new User but WITHOUT a emailaddress. BUT in my User class the email is unique and can not be null.

That means I have to create a new User class named TransUser.

Now I want to be able to have this as a class that is the same as the App\Entity\User class but without the email - column or at least with a email column that is not unique and can be null.

What is the best way to do this in PHP with Symfony?

Comment: Create fake emails and set email to this fake email on `prePersist` for example.

Comment: unique usually doesn't mean that it can't be null ... or multiple nulls for multiple rows (learned that the hard way ^^). so just allow nulls ... and for your validators ... probably have to figure out, only to validate the email, when it's a normal user.

Comment: did you tried to use fosuserBundle? it will make your work faster and more secure

Comment: @ A.Marwan - I builded my own security system - for me FosUserBundle was not flexible enough.

Comment: @Jakumi - U solved the second issue for me this day :D. Plz write the solution as answer - I will up-vote it and mark it as solution for my problem. Thank you!

Comment: @Slowwie done. ;o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could modify your `User` class to allow null email addresses. (`UNIQUE` still allows this).

however, on the registration/validation/login you ultimately have to distinguish the different user types.

this solution is somewhat class extensions (or single-table inheritance). But somewhere you'll probably have a quasi discriminator column. ;o)

obviously, the advantage is, that you can have a single user table, which makes all the referencing/foreign keys easier.

Answer (score 2):

you can have classes for users as many as you want, you only  need to define this new classes as user provider in your security.yaml in providers section for example you can have backend users beside regular users. this is how your provider section in security.yaml would looks like

```
providers:
    backend_users:
        entity:
            class: App\Entity\BackendUser
    users:
        entity:
            class: App\Entity\User
```

and so on , you can find more about it [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/user_provider.html).
you need to update firewall parts if you want to limit the type of users reaching some routes and add the provider key foreach firewall,something like this

```
main:
 logout:
   path: app_logout
 anonymous: true
 provider: backend_users
 guard:
    #....
```

you can find about it [here](https://symfony.com/doc/4.0/security/multiple_user_providers.html)

Comment: Hm, I think for my project I don't need this - because none of my users without an emailaddress will ever log in. But thank u for the effort.

Answer (score 2):

https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/tutorials/override-field-association-mappings-in-subclasses.html

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="user2")
 *
 * @ORM\AttributeOverrides({
 *      @ORM\AttributeOverride(name="email",
 *          column=@ORM\Column(
 *              name     = "email",
 *              type     = "string",
 *              nullable = true
 *          )
 *      ),
 *      @ORM\AttributeOverride(name="emailCanonical",
 *          column=@ORM\Column(
 *              name     = "email_canonical",
 *              type     = "string",
 *              nullable = true
 *          )
 *      )
 * })
 *
 */
class User2 extends User
{

}
```

Comment: This is also a good answer and I am curious about if it could solve my problem. But I stick with the solution of Jakumi. This way I have not to create a new User Class at all. But thank your for your time!